# Are color gradients possible in regular HTML?

Tags: html

I'm looking for a way to get a color gradient within a cell in a table.  I found a couple examples examples online that involve CSS or Javascript, but trying to stay away from those.

For example, I found this:

```
<table style="filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient(endColorstr='#C0CFE2', startColorstr='#FFFFFF', gradientType='0');">
```

The `Mircorosft" scares a bit for compatibility.  This is for email marketing, so it needs to be as simple as possible because email clients are rather limitted in rendering html.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Will this be in the email or will it be in a age the email links to?

Comment: Will be in the email.  I mean theres always the option of "Can't view this page?", but then that defeats the purpose of it being in the email.

Comment: Your example is using CSS, yet you say you don't want to use CSS?

Comment: I found the example online that accomplishes the desired affect if CSS was an option.  I am looking for an HTML equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

Email clients are the worst in terms of rendering your HTML and CSS, so try to be as minimalistic as you can. The CSS gradients won't work in 90% of clients, so avoid it.

The best solution probably to put a solid background color (so it will be shown before the images are loaded, if loaded) and add a background image.

Answer (score 0):

Check out CSS3 gradients. There are lots of generators on the web to try out, such as this one. http://gradients.glrzad.com/

In terms of browser compatibility, this table will show you the way:

http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gradients

Comment: Email clients, probably not but if they do support it, these will work.

Comment: Not necessarily either: http://blog.mailermailer.com/2011/04/background-images-in-html-email-the-naked-truth/

Answer (score 0):

I would put background pictures. This will make sure email client will show it.

Comment: Not necessarily, background images don't always show up in all clients. http://blog.mailermailer.com/2011/04/background-images-in-html-email-the-naked-truth/

Comment: Normally there no images at all. But after user approvals u can see all of them. I think HTML5 is not a case for Email clients, unless they web based.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no universal solution that will work on email clients. Your best bet is to use a pregenerated background image but now days most clients block images by default